# Wrong system time on startup

Tags: boot, time

I just installed elementary OS 5.1.2 Hera, and noticed that whenever I boot up, the system time is wrong, and it takes about a minute to automatically correct. This is an issue me because I use the Nigh Light feature and this causes it to be active even when it should not.

I'd gladly appreciate if someone could point me out towards a solution.

Comment: If you say that it corrects itself after a minute, you could look into logs if there is something happening there. Note how much time passed from turning on the computer to getting correct time and then use `dmesg | less` to browse the log to that time point, where it corrected. You can also try `journalctl -k`, which gives real time instead of "seconds from boot".